# UIFont Sizes: half point sizes possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uikit, uifont

I was wondering why there is no differences between these three:

```
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:f size:10.0];
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:f size:10.5];
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:f size:10.9];
```

The font will be shown at 10, no matter what. Will the font size be converted from CGFloat to an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the font size is being changed but less than 1 increment is very less i.e. our eyes unable to figure it out. You can see it after getting the `textView` **font size**.
After each increment `NSLog` the **font Size** of `textView` then see what does it print ..

```
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0];
float fontSize1 = textView.font.pointSize;
NSLog(@"fontSize1 = %f",fontSize1);

textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.5];
float fontSize2 = textView.font.pointSize;
NSLog(@"fontSize2 = %f",fontSize2);

textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.9];
float fontSize3 = textView.font.pointSize;
NSLog(@"fontSize3 = %f",fontSize3);
```

You will get it like this:

**fontSize1 = 10.000000**

**fontSize2 = 10.500000**

**fontSize3 = 10.900000**